# Urgent request for help. Why is the format displayed incorrectly?

Tags: margins

I am uploading my paper to a conference website. I am sure that the body of my paper has only 11 pages. But the format check on the website keeps showing:

> This document may violate the submission format requirements.
>
> Margins too small: text height exceeds 9.25in by 6% (page 13).
> Submissions that violate the requirements will not be considered.
> However, the automated format checker can misreport errors (for
> instance, it can miscalculate margins and text sizes for certain
> figures). If you are confident that the paper respects all format
> requirements, you may keep the current submission as is.

When I delete half a page, the display passed. What is the reason for this? The deadline for submission tonight. Due to the time difference, I can no longer ask the conference organizer. What could be the reason for this?

The conference I want to contribute to is: https://hpca-conf.org/2022/guidelines-for-submissions/

I added the following libraries. The rest is the text.

```
%[Yujie]
\usepackage[ruled,lined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newlength{\restofline}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{keywordcolor}{RGB}{157,0,129}
\definecolor{commentcolor}{RGB}{157,0,129}
\definecolor{numbercolor}{RGB}{120,120,120}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=frm,placement={!ht},name=Listing]{listing}

%[Yujie] command
\newcommand{\myline}{\vspace{-0.7\baselineskip}\hrulefill\vspace{-0.1\baselineskip}}
```

I used some pictures. I used some pictures. I am not sure if I can use \subfloat and \usepackage{subfig} libraries.

```
\begin{figure*}[htb]
    \centering
    \subfloat[$d=1$]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{hpca/oneBit_d=1.pdf}}
    \quad
    \subfloat[$d=4$]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{hpca/oneBit_d=4.pdf}}
    \quad
    \subfloat[$d=8$]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{hpca/oneBit_d=8.pdf}}\\
    \caption{Example sequences observed by the receiver when the sender continuously sends random sequences.}
    \label{binarySeq}
\end{figure*}
```

[image]

Comment: This is hardly a question that can be answered here (or actually by anyone except for the conference organisers). It seems that your document gets reformatted or at least some pages are added. Maybe the problematic part is inside the section you deleted? It says that you can keep the formatting, if you are sure that it does not violate the rules. So, in this case you may just keep it the way it is.

Comment: The error is about exceeding text height. So, make sure the page margins are correct.  You can set up this using the `geometry` package for example. Or maybe there is an image or a table on one page that overlaps the bottom page margin.

Comment: But I did not change its parameters. I just added some of the packages above.

Comment: If you only provide the packages, it is even more impossible to guess where the problem may be. Please do at least provide a MWE, including the document class and some example paragraph. I fear that nobody here will be able to help you anyways. All we can provide is some guesses ... Like I said: Look for boxes that overlap the page margins, especially at the bottom of each page.

Comment: I added the commands I used to draw pictures. Can these commands be used?https://github.com/kohler/hotcrp/blob/master/src/checkformat.php  The website seems to be checked using this script.

Comment: This should be okay. You can look for overlapping stuff by putting `\usepackage{showframe}` inside your preamble (delete before submission). Do you get any warnings when compiling you document that hint to overfull boxes?

Comment: I just added \usepackage{showframe}. Then compile again. There are no errors or exceptions. All the text is in the box. And a total of 11 pages of text.  I placed a screenshot after compilation.

Comment: Well, if you tried this and you could make sure that there is actually nothing wrong with your submission, I would suggest that you just submit it as it is. I am really sorry, but with just this information and without knowing about your actual document (which I can totally understand that you don't want to publish here) it is very close to impossible to come up with any better suggestion ...

Comment: thank you. I found the problem. The problem is in the references. Page 13 is the reference. Because page 13 is only half a page. So it has been showing that there is a problem with the margin. How can I display the references evenly in two columns?

Comment: Hard to say. From your sreenshot you have at least 22 references. Perhaps use a shorter notation OR provide a link to a dedicated webpage, where you list all references. (E.g. cut your list at ref#16 and point to said page) .... if that's ok for the conference organizers.

Comment: This will not change the number of pages (that now seem to be  13, not 11 ...) and moreover,  without see the guidelines, most probably you should **not** change the format of the template in any form. The templates are just to avoid personal preferences about the format, to ensure that every paper will have the same style. So, reduce the text and/or  the number of references and do not play with margins, text size, interline spacing, bibliography style, or any other form of change the format.

Comment: Thank you very very much! I just asked about it, and their answer was a question about the format check script. They let me keep the submission as it is. thank you!